# Go - httpRequest.Write(), pass a long request to a Writer without being cut off?

Tags: go

Creating a request, then writing it

```
var w CustomWriter

req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/Foo", bytes.NewReader([]byte(<very long string>)))
req.Write(w)

func (w *CustomWriter) Write(request []byte) (int, error) {
    fmt.Println(len(request))

    return 0, nil
}
```

Output: 4096

But the body of my request is noticeably longer, but it just gets cut off when trying to write it. How do I write and send this HTTP Request that has a very long body without the body being lost or cut off?

Comment: Not that this is the problem, but use `strings.NewReader(<very long string>)` instead of `bytes.NewReader([]byte(<very long string>)`.  The former avoids the allocation in the `[]byte` conversion.

Comment: are you trying to accomplish what httputil.DumpRequest does, while avoiding the large byte array coming back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with the request being turned into a huge array, this is already part of the Go stdlib:

```
import "net/http/httputil"

...
    rData, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
...


...

func debugResponse(resp *http.Response) {
    dump, _ := httputil.DumpResponse(resp, true)
    fmt.Println("DEBUG:")
    fmt.Printf("%q", dump)
}
```

Once you consume the response or request, you have to assume that it has been held in memory.  Use the flag false if you don't want to print the body because it's large or binary.

Comment: Is there a function read the dump back into a http.Request? `req, err := http.ReadRequest(bufio.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(rData)))` seems to ignore the body even when body is actually in the byte array.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you execute HTTP requests in Go. You need to do

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/Foo", bytes.NewReader([]byte(<very long string>)))
client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

Comment: I'm trying to pass the http request to a custom writer not execute it

Comment: Can you show the complete source code and explain your overall goal (not just how you are trying to do it)? Thanks

Comment: Write takes an io.Writer interface which is defined as `type Writer interface {
        Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}` your own write does not return anything.

Comment: The goal is to pass a http request as a byte array to a custom writer

Comment: I think you need to return len(request),nil to tell the caller to carry on writing. What you see is just an artifact of the length of the internal buffer.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the case! I returned 0, nil which caused the problem